# Can I create my own status codes for my business logic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

Since there are a lot of numbers which aren't status codes. can i create my own status code (For Eg: 444). I heard that rendering our own status codes in rails application deployed in phusion passenger gives you a 500? Is it true. If so, how can we create our own status codes for business logic purpose?

Comment: You probably shouldn't, your business logic and HTTP status codes should exist at very different layers.

Comment: Having your business logic rely on certain HTTP codes isn't the worst idea in the world. You should have logical response codes. People don't use them enough in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a specific status code all you have to add into the controller action is

```
render :status => 444
```

Comment: Yes the status can be rendered in rails using the above method. But creating our own status code, and rendering in rails server deployed in passenger, is returning 500 instead of 444.

Comment: Getting a 500 in production likely indicates an actual error, and not just Passenger's substitution for your arbitrary status code. Have you checked your logs?

Comment: The issue we have found is the status code we are rendering is not listed in the accepted status codes of Apache server

Answer (score 0):

Status codes that are returned should be in the list of Apache Web Server accepted status codes.